# What is the programming language used in dockerfile and docker-compose files

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

What is the programming language used in docker file and docker-compose files.

We use dockerfile to build docker images.
So what is the language used to develop a dockerfile?

Comment: It's not really a language, it's a file format called YAML. https://yaml.org/

Answer (score 17):

- **Docker** is written in the GO language
- A **Dockerfile** is just a text file. It is a script that contains collections of commands and instructions that will be automatically executed in sequence in the docker environment for building a new docker image.
- A **docker-compose.yml** file is used for docker-compose, if you are using that feature of Docker.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
Question: If its just a text file we see few instructions predefined like FROM, ENV, COPY, USER,CMD.

As part of what we can define these predefined keywords.

Comment: Currently there are about a dozen different set of commands which Dockerfiles can contain to have Docker build an image. These commands are understood by the docker daemon to build an image.